# Creating a list with repeating element

Tags: java

Is there an utility method in Java that generates a list or array of a specified length with all elements equal to a specified value (e.g ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo"])?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

You can use [`Collections.nCopies`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,%20T)). Note that this copies the *reference* to the given object, not the object itself. If you're working with strings, it won't matter because they're immutable anyway.

```
List<String> list = Collections.nCopies(5, "foo");
System.out.println(list);
```

```
[foo, foo, foo, foo, foo]
```

Comment: flawless answer!

Comment: note - this returns an immutable collection

Comment: note - this will evaluate `"foo"` even if `n = 0`

Answer (score 37):

For an array you can use [Arrays.fill(Object[] a, Object val)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object))

```
String[] strArray = new String[10];
Arrays.fill(strArray, "foo");
```

and if you need a list, just use

```
List<String> asList = Arrays.asList(strArray);
```

> Then I have to use two lines: String[] strArray = new String[5]; Arrays.fill(strArray, "foo");. Is there a one-line solution?

You can use [Collections.nCopies(5, "foo")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,%20T)) as a one-line solution to get a list :

```
List<String> strArray = Collections.nCopies(5, "foo");
```

or combine it with `toArray` to get an array.

```
String[] strArray = Collections.nCopies(5, "foo").toArray(new String[5]);
```

Comment: Then I have to use two lines: `String[] strArray = new String[5]; Arrays.fill(strArray, "foo");`. Is there a one-line solution?

Comment: Very simple: Collections.nCopies(5, "foo") Thkns!

Answer (score 20):

If your object are not immutable or not reference-transparent, you can use

```
Stream.generate(YourClass::new).limit(<count>)
```

and collect it to list

```
.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

or to array

```
.toArray(YourClass[]::new)
```

Answer (score 12):

Version you can use for primitive arrays(Java 8):

```
DoubleStream.generate(() -> 123.42).limit(777).toArray(); // returns array of 777 123.42 double vals
```

Note that it returns `double[]`, not `Double[]`

Works for IntegerStream, DoubleStream, LongStream

**UPD**

and for string dups you can use:

`Stream.generate(() -> "value").limit(400).toArray()`

No extra libs required, single line

Answer (score 11):

Using `IntStream`, you can generate a range of integers, map them to the element you want and collect it as a list.

```
List<String> list = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 5)
            .mapToObj(i -> "foo")
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, as an array

```
 String[] arr = IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 5)
            .mapToObj(i -> "foo")
            .toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: works flawlessly